# SwiftData: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: swift, swift-data

everyone. I encountered the error message in the title of this post thrown by Xcode 15.0.1 for the following code which uses SwiftData with SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
final class PorcelineTile {
    @Attribute (.unique) var name: String
    var additionalInfo: String
    var pattern: [String: Double]

    init(name: String, pattern: [String: Double] = ["":0.0], additionalInfo: String = "") {
        self.name = name
        self.additionalInfo = additionalInfo
        self.pattern = pattern
    }

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var items: [Item]
}
```

I have tried commenting out any one or two of the three properties and their corresponding mappings in the initialiser but the error message just wouldn't go away. I'm really puzzled what could've gone wrong. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You didn't initialise `items`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Ok, I did `@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var items: [Item] = []` and it worked. However, I watched a video about SwiftData basics which was published 4 months ago. In the video, the example didn't initialise the `items` property and no error message appeared. Maybe Xcode updated its rules about relationship properties.

Comment: If you can post a link to that video, I might be able to explain to you why they didn't initialise `items` there.

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper. The link to that video is https://youtu.be/0CQHc9Wz25Q?si=YFg6jdUEEx52E-1D Plus, I think it would be awkward to furnish every relationship variable declaration with a default initialisation statement esp. when the object is particularly complicated.

Comment: It's a fundamental requirement of a Swift initialiser. Nothing to do with SwiftData or relationships.

Comment: That video was created with an Xcode beta, so it probably had some bugs

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11. That's true. We cannot leave any property unitialised in Swift unless they're declared as an Optional which virtually means they're initially assigned a `nil`. So, in my case, I could've done `@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var items: [Item]?` instead of assigning an initialisation expression.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one linked. That one is about failure to initialise an optional `let`. This is about failure to initialise a non optional `var`. The rules are different.

Comment: @MichaelMay you could make it optional, but why not just initialise it to an empty array?

Comment: Looks like OP should remove this question or post their own answer with whatever solution was finally chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your participation, everyone. I agree with the solution by some of you that a default value can be provided to the `items` var or `items` can be declared as an `Optional`.